# How to answer client after weekend?

Tags: professionalism, email, clients

Actually I want to send an email to my client after weekend. So I am confused that is it formal to say "Hope you had a nice weekend". I want to write an email in professional way because I can't lose my client.

How I start my email which convinced him to stay in-touch with me. Any help would be appreciated?

**Edited:**

Actually the client which I have mentioned above is an expert of company. I am working on their open-source product and I got some issue.

On this issue our discussion was continued and after weekend I am afraid that may he will not reply to my question because I wasn't answered to his questions though I have more responsibility because the problem is mine and he is just help me out.

May he felt aggressive upon not getting any response and close the discussion. 
If this happen first of all I can't get any further knowledge or information from him (Who is expert and experienced person) and secondly It's very difficult for me to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you have other clients? How do you handle them? What is so important about him? What makes you feel that you will lose him?

Comment: I need some information from my client and at weekend I was busy so I am not answering about what he asked? So after two days I want to send him an professional email so that I can convince him that I am back and say sorry for the late response.

Comment: @Zeb: Please edit that information into your question, we need some context to answer. Also, please explain why you think answering on Monday is "late".  Is there any agreement on how quickly you are supposed to answer?

Comment: @Zeb Was your client expecting you to work during the weekend and respond to the email? If not, I don't see why a mail sent on Monday in response to a discussion on Friday is "two days late".

Comment: Have you had any correspondence with this person before?

Comment: No @JeffO, this is first time I corresponding with him.

Comment: No @Happy! he is actually not expecting me to work at weekend but I think it's unethical that he is indicating something and I am not prompt him on time. That's why I think "two days late" matters alot.

Comment: @Zeb Each person is entitled to their own definition of "ethical". If you think that being ethical means working 24x7 without any break, then feel free to work accordingly. There's the small matter of not too many people agreeing with you that you might want to consider, but it isn't really that important.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe you're overthinking it.

> Hello name,
>
> Hope you had a nice weekend!
>
> Regarding the issue we discussed last week, what do you think of [...]

I have a hard time imagining this being a bad idea, unless you know he spent his weekend at a funeral or something.

Since you give no information as to whether or not this particular client is special in any way, I'd simply stick to vanilla.

Comment: yes, professional doesn't mean "soulless". Asking if he had a nice weekend is just a nice beginning. I don't know about the semi colon - it might be the "proper" use of it, but they're so rare these days.

Comment: @bharal - Yeah, the semicolon was maybe in excess, but that's outside the scope anyway.

Comment: @bharal - Shouldn't a semicolon separate two sentences and not a phrase and a sentence unless there is also a transitional phrase separating the two? If you're going to say, "what you think of..." why even bother with punctuation?

Comment: Edited. It's a bad habit of mine. I misuse them a lot.

Comment: @Alec- Edited part is  clearly understandable for everyone which one is edited part and which one is writer's previous opinion.